# Modify a binary tree in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with 7 elements which currently looks like this:

```
   1
 5   2
7 6 4 3
```

I am trying to traverse it in postorder and relable the elements as I go, so that it looks like this:

```
    7
  3  6
1 2 4 5
```

using the following function, which is part of my `Tree` class:

```
def relable(self, h):
    if self.root is not None:
        self._relable(self.root, h)
def _relable(self, node, h):
    if node is not None:
        self._relable(node.l, h-2)
        self._relable(node.r, h-1)
        node = Node(h)
```

The rest of my `Tree` class is more or less the same as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864021/5415895).
I populated the tree by `add`ing the numbers 1-7 in a loop.

However, when I call `tree.relable(7)`, and then print the tree, the tree is the same.
I'm guessing this has something to do with how Python passes arguments (I'm a C++ programmer) but I don't know how to fix this.
The entirety of my code can be fount [here](https://gist.github.com/TexAgg/22f72e5e88feb28732aaebb31c16ccc4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node = Node(h)` is just assigning a local variable, it doesn't have any effect on the `node` parameter that was passed to the function. You need to actually modify the node, i.e. `node.v = h`.