# Creating a binary tree through a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I want to create a binary tree by iterating through a loop. I know how to write a very basic binary tree.

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = None


root = Tree()
root.data = 75
root.left = Tree()
root.left.data = 95
root.right = Tree()
root.right.data = 64

root.left.left = Tree()
root.left.left.data = 32
root.left.right = Tree()
root.left.right.data = 93
root.left.left = Tree()
root.right.left.data = 32
root.left.right = Tree()
root.right.right.data = 93

print(root.data)
```

This is tedious handtyping it, and if I were to have a list of numbers:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and put it through a loop to create a binary tree in this order so:

```
   1 
 2   3
4 5 6 7
```

How would I write that? and because I'm using this to calculate the sum of all the paths, how do you navigate/iterate through a binary tree:

Comment: Does node 5 belong to node 2 or 3, or to both of them?

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598437/how-to-implement-a-binary-tree). Not a complete dup though because the OP wants to automate the process of creating the tree.

Comment: You'd need to keep track of the current tree height.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I dont understand what a node is. I am very new to binary trees.

Comment: @PoChenLiu Node = a number in the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build a full **binary tree** (*not necessarily* a binary search tree) from a list of node values, let's assume values in the list are ordered according to level-order traversal. So, a list from your question

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

will represent a tree:

```
   1 
 2   3
4 5 6 7
```

Notice that the root value is at the position `0`, its left child is at the position `1*2-1=1`, the right child at `1*2=2`, etc. In general for a node in the list at index `i`, its left child is at position `(i+1)*2-1`, and the right child at `(i+1)*2`.

Now, we simply need to build the tree recursively, node by node, at each step creating the left and the right subtree.

To make it simpler, let's assume the list of `values` is global.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def buildTree(i):
    if i < len(values):
        return Node(values[i], left=buildTree((i+1)*2-1), right=buildTree((i+1)*2))

values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
tree = buildTree(0)
```

To print-out the tree, we can use the [preorder tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order):

```
def preorder(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    yield node.data
    for v in preorder(node.left):
        yield v
    for v in preorder(node.right):
        yield v
```

Like this:

```
>>> print list(preorder(tree))
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: If I were to have node 5 be shared by 2 and 3 how would I do that?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what do you mean by that? If you want a node (5) to have *two parents* (2 and 3 above), then you need a general [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), not [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) (which is a special type of graph).