# Binary Tree implementation with Separate class for node and tree

Tags: python-3.x, oop, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am new to Python and data structures. While learning binary tree, I found all the available implementations have the methods of the tree inside the node class.

But I want to implement it differently, where along with the Node class, there will be a Binary tree class, which will contain the methods of the Binary tree.

This is the code I came up with, but it raises an error with the arguments I am passing to the functions `insertleft()` and `insertright()`.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = arg

class Bt():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def insertleft(temp.left, data):    
        if (temp.left == None):
            temp.left.data = data
        elif(data<temp.left.data):
            t1 = temp.left
            insertleft(t1.left, data)
        elif(data>temp.left.data):
            t1 = temp.left
            insertright(t1.left, data)

    def insertright(temp.right, data):  
        if (temp.right == None):
            temp.right.data = data
        elif(data<temp.right.data):
            t1 = temp.right
            insertleft(t1.right, data)
        elif(data>temp.right.data):
            t1 = temp.right
            insertright(t1.right, data)


    def insert(self, data):
        temp = self.root
        if(temp.data = None):
            temp.data = data
        elif(data<temp.data):
            insertleft(temp.left, data)
        elif(data>temp.data):
            insertright(temp.right, data)


r = Bt()
r.root = Node(5)
r.insert(4)
r.insert(6)
```

These is the error I received:

> ```
> def insertleft(temp.left, data):  
>                       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

I am not sure what the right syntax should be. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You are *defining* a function inside a class. The first argument should be a variable that represents the instantiated class object it`self`. The following arguments are references to passed in parameters. So `temp.left` should be just `temp` or `node` in your case. You have some other issues with the logic as well...

Comment: Also, found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864021/1708751) with what seems like you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *define* a function, you also **define** the parameters you will be accepting. Inside a class though, as long as the method is not static or a class method, the first parameter should be `self` or a variable that represents the instanciated object itself.

In your case, you are already passing the value of `temp.left` and `temp.right` when calling the function. Changing the function definitions to just use `temp` should work just fine. Or even more readible, `node` since that is what you are actually referring to.

Your `insertleft` and `insertright` functions do the same thing as `insert`, and including them is not necessary. Just modify the `insert` function to do it all.

Here's what the end result should resemble:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = arg

class Bt():
    def __init__(self, root=None):  #Added default value
        self.root = Node(root)

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root.data is None:
            self.root.data = data   #Set the root data if it doesn't exist.
        else:
            self._insert(self.root, data)   #Prime the helper function with root node

    def _insert(self, node, data):    #Insert helper function to do the insertion
        if data < node.data:    #Check if data needs to be inserted on the left
            if node.left is None:   #Set left node if it doesn't exist
                node.left = Node(data)
            else:                   #Else let the left node decide where it goes as a child
                self._insert(node.left, data)
        else:                   #Else data needs to be inserted on the right
            if node.right is None:  #Set right node if it doesn't exist
                node.right = Node(data)
            else:                   #Else let the right node decide where it goes as a child
                self._insert(node.right, data)


r = Bt(5)
r.insert(4)
r.insert(6)
```

Now you're just missing functions to print the Tree and Data... and accessing the data.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. :)

Comment: This is the my search node implementation:

Answer (score 0):

Each Node in the binary search tree is considered as a another binary search tree. Hence we don't need to create a separate class for node.