# Calculator to basic operations with recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I am struggling with this recursion problem. I want to create a calculator to basic operations in python with recursion.

```
ops = {"+": (lambda x,y: x+y), "-": (lambda x,y: x-y), "*": (lambda x,y: x*y)}

def calculator(expr):
   for i in expr:
       if type(i) != tuple:
           return (ops[expr[1]] (expr[0],expr[2]))
       else:
           return calculator((i))
```

for `calculator(((1, '+', 2), '*', 3))`  I expected `9` but i get `(1, '+', 2, 1, '+', 2, 1, '+', 2)`

Please can you help?

Comment: `i` will never equal `tuple`.  Instead use `type(i) != tuple`

Comment: You also don't need the loop.  You can just check `type(expr[0]) != tuple`

Comment: But this still won't work if `expr[0]` is not a `tuple` but `expr[2]` is, since you're never evaluating `expr[2]` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically writing a binary tree traversal, specifically a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree). Using a tuple is one way to represent the tree (although there are better ways, like actually [implementing a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598437/how-to-implement-a-binary-tree)).

Now, about your code. Your expression can come in two different forms: a number or a tuple. The first one is just a simple boring number. The tuple will serve to represent a more complex expression. Because it's a binary tree, the tuples will always have three elements.

The following code should work.

```
#ops is defined as you defined it
def calculate(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, int): # this is the terminating condition for your recursion
        return expr
    if isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return ops[expr[1]](calculate(expr[0]), calculate(expr[2]))
```

The code will output the final integer result. Of course, you can also use other numerical types (e.g. `float`). For starting out recursion in python, this is fine.

P.S.: code isn't tested, do tell if it doesn't work.

Comment: On quick visual inspection, it can't work as `calculate(expr)` takes one argument but  the last line calls it with two: `(calculate(expr[0], expr[2])`.  And the parentheses aren't balanced.  My guess is you want: `(calculate(expr[0]), calculate(expr[2]))`

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. I fixed the code in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'll ever recurse in this…

a couple of immediate issues:

- `i` will never be `tuple`, but it might sometimes be an instance of one: you can check with `isinstance(i, tuple)`
- you're never evaluating the parameters to your operations

this will cause your code to do:

1. `calculator(((1, '+', 2), '*', 3))`
2. `ops['*']((1, '+', 2), 3)`
3. `(1, '+', 2) * 3`

note that "multiplying" a `list` or `tuple` by `n` will cause it's elements to be repeated `n` times — which is what you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

Your evaluation logic is off -- given these simple expressions, we're really only concerned with two cases, tuple or not tuple.  If it's a tuple, we apply the embedded binary operator to the recursive call of `calculator()` on the two arguments.  If it's not a tuple, just return it as-is:

```
OPERATIONS = { \
    "+": (lambda x, y: x + y), \
    "-": (lambda x, y: x - y), \
    "*": (lambda x, y: x * y), \
}

def calculator(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return OPERATIONS[expr[1]](calculator(expr[0]), calculator(expr[2]))

    return expr

print(calculator(((1, '+', 2), '*', 3)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
9
>
```

My believe is, if you try to do anything more sophisticated with this simple code, you'll quickly run into problems.