# How do I make TreeNode from list by Python

Tags: python, treenode

Lately, I started "leetcode" for studying programming. Sometimes, I encounter the question which is related to TreeNode.
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-univalue-path/

I usually run code in local to make sure if my code work. But those questions require me to prepare for TreeNode in advance, otherwise, I can not run in local. I don't know how to build TreeNode from a list.

I want to make TreeNode from a list by Python, like here.

```
class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.left = None
         self.right = None

input: [5,4,5,1,1,5]

output:
TreeNode{val: 5, left: TreeNode{val: 4, left: TreeNode{val: 1, left: None, right: None}, right: TreeNode{val: 1, left: None, right: None}}, right: TreeNode{val: 5, left: TreeNode{val: 5, left: None, right: None}, right: None}}
```

I know we can make sure whether the code work or not on leetcode. However, I think it's slow for me to check the code on leetcode. I would like to run my code in local. I hope you will help me.

Comment: In your output, you have 5 nodes: 5, 4, 1, 1, 5. However, you have 6 nodes in your input: 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5. Is this a typo?

Comment: I guess output has 6 nodes. Thanks for your reaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement a Binary Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598437/how-to-implement-a-binary-tree)

Comment: You're right. This is ducplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LeetCode's official explanation https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883654-What-does-1-null-2-3-mean-in-binary-tree-representation- of how their serialized formatting of a binary tree into the kind of list you see in their test cases works. If you want to run your solution against those test cases locally, you'll also need to write some code (or I'm sure you can find some online) that will input a serialized list, build the tree, and return the tree's root TreeNode so you can pass it to your `find_longest_univalue_path` function.

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is what you need:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
 
def creatBTree(data, index):
    pNode = None
    if index < len(data):
        if data[index] == None:
            return
        pNode = TreeNode(data[index])
        pNode.left = creatBTree(data, 2 * index + 1) # [1, 3, 7, 15, ...]
        pNode.right = creatBTree(data, 2 * index + 2) # [2, 5, 12, 25, ...]
    return pNode
```

Say you are cracking [pathSum](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/), populate the tree by calling

```
lst = [5,4,8,11,None,13,4,7,2,None,None,None,1]
root = creatBTree(lst, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the createBtree function code, Can you please clarify what the "index" parameter is for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is just beautified [StefanPochmann](https://leetcode.com/problems/recover-binary-search-tree/discuss/32539/Tree-Deserializer-and-Visualizer-for-Python)'s solution which was described at
[LeetCode's Help Center](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883654-What-does-1-null-2-3-mean-in-binary-tree-representation-)

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TreeNode({})'.format(self.val)


def deserialize(string):
    if string == '[]':
        return None
    nodes = [None if val == 'null' else TreeNode(int(val))
             for val in string.strip('[]').split(',')]
    kids = nodes[::-1]
    root = kids.pop()
    for node in nodes:
        if node:
            if kids:
                node.left = kids.pop()
            if kids:
                node.right = kids.pop()
    return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = deserialize('[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]')
    assert tree == TreeNode(3, TreeNode(9), TreeNode(20, TreeNode(15), TreeNode(7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a drop-in replacement for the incomplete class LeetCode provides in questions such as https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/

```py
import json

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        # Shrink the long json string by removing unnecessary lines
        t = '\n'.join([l for l in self.json_repr.split('\n')
            if '[' not in l and ']' not in l])
        return t.replace(',','')

    @property
    def json_repr(self):
        if self.val is None:
            return 'None'
        # Recursively construct a json-compliant representation
        if self.left is None:
            text = f"[{self.val}]"
        else:
            text = f"[{self.val}, [{self.left.json_repr}, {self.right.json_repr}]]"
        return json.dumps(json.loads(text), indent=1)

    def from_list(l):
        nodes = [TreeNode(v) for v in l]
        kids = nodes[::-1]
        root = kids.pop()
        for node in nodes:
            if node:
                if kids:
                    node.left = kids.pop()
                if kids:
                    node.right = kids.pop()
        return root

t = TreeNode.from_list([4,2,7,1,3,6,9])
print(t)
```

Returns:

```
 4
   2
     1
     3
   7
     6
     9
```