# insert value binary tree using python

Tags: python

i want to create a binary tree program but the final result returns unwanted result .i tried to compare the values ​​in it but i think it's the wrong way to get the right result.

the binary tree should be show the output :

```
15 25 20 30 10 7 13 14 6 9 11 17 27 32 23
root node : 6
```

this my program when i was create:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.left=None
    self.value=value
    self.right=None
  def insert(self, value):
    if self.value:
      if value < self.value:
        if self.left is None:
          self.left = Node(value)
        else:
          self.left.insert(value)
      elif value > self.value:
        if self.right is None:
          self.right = Node(value)
        else:
          self.right.insert(value)
    else:
      self.value = value
  def printTree(self):
    if self.left:
      self.left.printTree()
      print( self.value),
    if self.right:
      self.right.printTree()

root=Node(6)

root.insert(15)
root.insert(25)
root.insert(20)
root.insert(30)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(7)
root.insert(13)
root.insert(14)

root.insert(9)
root.insert(11)
root.insert(17)
root.insert(27)
root.insert(32)
root.insert(23)

root.printTree()
```

i need your opinion to fix this program.

Comment: What is your *expected* output??
There are three ways to present or traverse through a binary tree: InOrder PreOrder and PostOrder. please be specific of how would you like your tree to be shown please.

Comment: the final result show : 15 25 20 30 10 7 13 14 6 9 11 17 27 32 23

Comment: you are sure you want to do that from scratch ? thought xml.etree.ElementTree could work for you

Comment: @rey why do you want to show the nodes in the same order you place them. while you can simply use a Queue instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.left.insert(value) and self.right.insert(value) is the wrong way
```

just do

```
self.left = value
self.right = value
```

becaues you are in the same class
there is no need to call a function for this task.

and than have a look at your state machine:

```
if self.left is None:
and 
if self.right is None:
```

This only matches if the value is None
after the first time assigning values to it, than all code in this if is completly ignored.

Another thing:

```
self.left = Node(value)
```

assigns the class Node with a value to your local inner class value left
which is not want you desire, you just simply wants the value assigned to self.left

Hopefully it helps?

Comment: so i delete all if else statement and only put if self.left is None:and  and if self.right is None: in insert function?

Comment: just google it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598437/how-to-implement-a-binary-tree ;)

Comment: There is nice presentation here: http://www.pythonschool.net/data-structures-algorithms/binary-tree/

The Tree is a data structure and needs somehow knowlegde about:
"how are my items are organized?"

"So my tree have Nodes?" --> "how can I reach them?"
"do I have something in left? do I have something in right?"
"is there an end?" --> if the left is None --> there is a left end
--> if the right is None --> there is a right end

Comment: And to print out those Node data, just print it if left is not None or if right is not Node
than go a level deeper in the Tree and ask the Node again: "Do I have something in left? Do I have something in right?"

That is all.

The binary tree it self, needs to know about it can have Nodes and add them, delete them, print them.